# Using sizeof() in array declarations in C89

Tags: c, arrays, clang, sizeof, c89

I was under the impression that variable-size array declarations were not possible in C89.  But, when compiling with `clang -ansi` I am able to run the following code:

```
double array[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
double other_array[sizeof(array)] = { 0.0 };
```

What is going on here?  Is that not considered a variable-size array declaration?

Comment: There are no variable size arrays in C89, so it could not be considered a variable size array declaration. .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because result of `sizeof` operator is *constant expression*, so it does not qualify for VLA, just like the following declaration:

```
int other_array[5];
```

cannot be variable length array either. From  C11 (N1570) §6.6/p6 *Constant expressions* (emphasis mine going forward):

> An *integer constant expression*<sup>117)</sup> shall have integer type and shall
>   only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
>   character constants, `sizeof` expressions **whose results are integer
>   constants**, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the
>   immediate operands of casts.

For sake of completeness, the `sizeof` operator does not always results into constant expression, though this only affects post-C89 standards (in C11 VLAs were made optional). Referring to §6.5.3.4/p2 *The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators*:

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the
>   operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the
>   result **is an integer constant**.

Answer (score 8):

In ANSI C89 a.k.a. ISO C90, the `sizeof` operator yields an *integer constant*, which is suitable for array dimensions. Function calls, for example, are not.

I'd like to add another remark, since I believe the code as-is has a problem that might get overlooked.

If the `other_array` is declared as

```
double other_array[sizeof(array)];
```

it will **neither have the same number of elements, nor the same size** (that would only be true for array of `char`) as `array[]`. If the intent is to declare a second array with the same number of elements (regardless of type), use this:

```
double other_array[sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)];
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this is not an answer to the question. This should be a comment.

Comment: @JensGustedt Fair enough. But I tried to actually *understand* what the code was supposed to achieve, see more than the technical question, uncover why someone would want another array the number of elements were one for each byte in a double array. That does not look right and the comments are simply too limited when it comes to formatting. Maybe I should repeat the technical answer a third time to conform to the answer expectation.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's see the criteria for an array (*not being*) a VLA. `C11` doc, chapter §6.7.6.2,

> [...] If the size is an integer constant expression
>   and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length
>   array type; [...]

Coming to your case, `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, so it produces a value that is considered compile time constant expression. An array definition, whose size is specified as a compile time constant expression is not a VLA. So, in your code,

```
int other_array[sizeof(array)]
```

is not a VLA.

Regarding the `sizeof` operator result, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. [...] otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and **the result is an integer constant.**

Comment: In C11 `sizeof` is not a "compile-time operator" and sometimes does not produce constant expression.  (Although OP was asking about C89)